# How to make a form using ajax, onchange event, reload to SAME page

Tags: ajax, forms, session, onchange

I've been studying this for a while and I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way because every form I setup according to examples, it doesn't do what I need.

I need to setup a form that will:

- set session when you select from dropdown menu
- not reload/refresh page (i've read that using AJAX solves this)
- submit and stay on SAME page (confused because most AJAX examples send it to different process.php page which is supposedly "invisible" but it doesn't "stay" on the same page, it redirects.

Basically, client selects quantity of 1 to 10.  If they select "2"... it does NOT reload the page.. but it DOES set a session[quantity]=2.  Should be simple...  but do I POST to same page as form?  or POST to different page and it somehow redirects?

Also, one test I did it kept pasting my "echo session[quantity]" down the page like 7, 2, 3, 5, etc. etc. each time instead of replacing it.

The code below is partly from an example which had gender as a dropdown menu.  I just want the dropdown to STAY as whatever was selected and also echo the selection next to the submit button.  This is for testing purposes so that I understand what is going on.  Once that happens I can do the rest of the form.  it currently won't echo anything.

```
<? ob_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Submit  Form with out refreshing page Tutorial</title>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".submit").click(function() {
var gender = $("#gender").val();
var dataString = 'gender=' + gender;
if(gender=='')
{
$('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "join.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(){
$('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body{
}
.error{
color:#d12f19;
font-size:12px;
}
.success{
color:#006600;
font-size:12px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body id="public">
<div style="height:30px"></div>
        <div id="container">
                    <div style="height:30px"></div>

                    <form method="post" name="form">
                        <select id="gender" name="gender">
                        <option value="">Gender</option>
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                        </select>
                        <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>
                        <span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
                        <span class="success" style="display:none"> Your gender is <?php echo $_SESSION['gender'];?></span>
                        </div>
                    </form>

        <div style="height:20px"></div>
        </div><!--container-->
</body>
</html>
<? ob_flush(); ?>
```

and here is my page where the POST goes called join.php (called that in example so I went with it for now)

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if($_POST)
{
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$_SESSION['gender'] = $gender;
}
else
{ }
?>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: jQuery or plain js? What server language?

Comment: I've tried again using a sample that had a dropdown asking for gender (male / female).  Still can't seem to paste code properly here.  Just a very ugly and basic test... you should be able to select "male" or "female" and the ajax will send selection to join.php which sets a session.  then on the main form, it should echo the session next to the submit button.

Comment: i'm a little closer.  but I can't figure out why when I add "onchange" to the form, it doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: I'm getting nowhere.  All I need is to find an example of how a form would be if the user selects from a dropdown menu, it takes that and uses ajax / jquery or whatever to send to a php page, sets as session, then on the form page it actually KEEPS the selection they chose due to the session variable that was just set.  My menu constantly either uses the first or last option.  Not the actual one selected.